# Capistrano - Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rake, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my project to a server via `capistrano` but I get below error and the deployment process fails to proceed:

```
** [out :: myprojet..] Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources
** [out :: myprojet..] Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I'm using `rvm`, however I removed `rake` and manually installed it.. also removed my `Gemfile.lock` and added `gem rake, '0.8.7'` to my Gemfile; also didn't worked.

I have the `rake` in my gem list:

```
$ gem list | grep rake
  rake (0.8.7)
```

I also added `set :rake, 'bundle exec rake'` to `deploy.rb` file but I still get this error. Any idea? tnx.

Comment: this is not clear in your question and I'm almost sure that this is the correct path to someone answer your question. If you are having a problem, maybe it is a good idea to give **all** information you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by specifying the `rvm` `Gemset` in `deploy.rb` file:

```
set :rvm_ruby_string, "ruby-1.9.2-p180@myproject"
set :rvm_type, :user
```

Answer (score 0):

Before deploy, try this

1. Remove all the versions of Rake ==> `gem uninstall rake`
2. Remove your `gemfile.lock` => `rm Gemfile.lock`
3. Remove `gem 'rake'` on your Gemfile
4. Run `bundle install`
5. Install Rake manually : `gem install rake --version=10.0.4`